# Is the method onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) called after onPause()?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-memory

I'm new to android and I read a book for beginners which said that `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` is ensured to be called before the system reclaims your `Activity`. 
I tried it on some test codes and found it incorrect. I found that `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` was called every time after `onPause()` was called. And it has nothing to do with system reclaimation. 
I'm not very sure about it, so that's the question: when is `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` called actually?

Comment: You should read about the activiy life cycle. Here's a diagram: http://i.stack.imgur.com/EVuKo.png

Comment: Thank you, dazito. I think I just got your point with the picture: `onPause()` itself is ensured to be called before system kill the Activity, so that's why `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` is ensured too. But I noticed that `onStop()` will certainly be called for less times than `onPause()` in one lifecycle, and `onStop()` is also ensured to be called before system kill the Activity. So why `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` always couples with `onPause()` but not `onStop()`? Why should `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` be called so many times? It seems to be kind of waste of resource to system.

Comment: Because you can have another activity taking the place (on the screen) of your current activity, therefore your onPause() is called. From Android Docs: `For example, when a semi-transparent activity opens (such as one in the style of a dialog), the previous activity pauses. As long as the activity is still partially visible but currently not the activity in focus, it remains paused.` http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html I recommend you to override all activity life cycles and play around so you can how the activity is paused/resumed/stopped/destroyed etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html):

> In addition, the method `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` is called before placing the activity in such a background state, allowing you to save away any dynamic instance state in your activity into the given Bundle, to be later received in `onCreate(Bundle)` if the activity needs to be re-created. See the Process Lifecycle section for more information on how the lifecycle of a process is tied to the activities it is hosting. Note that it is important to save persistent data in `onPause()` instead of `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` because the latter is not part of the lifecycle callbacks, so will not be called in every situation as described in its documentation.

Yes `onPause()` is called before `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)`. But `onPause()` is guaranteed to be called as its a part of activity [life cycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Usually when your activity is re-created for example when you change device orientation then `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` is called if you have not specified the `android:configChanges` tag in your `manifest.xml` file.

Answer (score 2):

I don't agree with a previous answer.
According to the [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29):

> If called, this method will occur before onStop(). There are no
>   guarantees about whether it will occur before or after onPause().

Comment: As an important note, `onSaveInstanceState()` may get called before `onPause()`. It might be due to the fact that the (support) Fragment I'm using is in the `ViewPager`. Hope this is helpful for someone else.